# Build url in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, urlhacking

I am trying to build a url in an aura component but I am only getting the name of the variable in the url

Current url that passing in the variable name and not its values

```
window.open('https://secure1.website.com/abcd/aaaa?cust.Name=%20CustName%20variable&cust.middleName=%20middleName&customer.email=newEmail&header.accountNumber=newrecordId&header.amount=payment&header.code=123');
```

Tried href but cannot deploy to org to test.  Assuming ampersands are issue since they are red in my code.

```
<a href="{!'https://secure1.website.com/abcd/aaaa?cust.firstName=%20'+CustName+'%20variable&customer.middleName=%20'+middleName+'&customer.email='+newEmail+'&header.accountNumber=newrecordId&header.amount=payment&header.code=123'}"></a>
```

I used the window.open option since I want to direct the user to a new tab.
CustName, middleName, newrecordId, newEmail are the parameters I am trying to add to the url.  The url was supplied and works with the exception that the values being passed in are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `window.open` url is wrapped in single quotes the variable names are interpreted as the literal string value. You can use the [javascript template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) feature, which uses the backtick character, to embed the variable value within the string.

Example:

```js
window.open(`https://example.com/abcd/aaaa?cust.Name=${CustName}&customer.middleName=${middleName}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Tyler.  When I try wrapping the variable in ${} the url no longer renders the page.  I will keep trying but if you have any additional suggestions let me know. thanks

Comment: Solved it.  had to separate the url and add variables as needed. window.open(`https://example.com/abcd/aaaa?cust.Name=' +CustName + ' customer.middleName' + .....